# Netbeans 7 and Jetty

Tags: netbeans, jetty

Is it possible to integrate Jetty with NetBeans 7?

Comment: I can't see why you would be having problems, could you elaborate?

Comment: @Tim Sparg - How is it done? If I click `Options -> Servers -> Add Server` there is no item in the list for Jetty. Having Google'd around, I cant find any evidence of Jetty being officially supported under NetBeans.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To this date there is no Jetty support with NetBeans. It is possible to use Jetty via Maven - http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/02/use-jetty-to-run-maven-web-applications.html.

Comment: I currently have Jetty working with some simple Java projects using Maven in Netbeans 8.  No problem from the embedded code side.  If you want to swap-in Jety as a server, you need to use **Tools** / Servers / *Add Server Instance* _wizard_ and follow the prompts.  Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/38577/jetty), but having never used it I can't vouch for how good it is or if it even works!

Comment: Yes, I found this before posting my question of SO. There is only one comment for the plugin, which opens with `IT DOES NOT WORK`. Anything else?

Comment: @WulfgarPro I saw the comment that said it may work with Jetty 6. Which By the way it doesn't (I just tried it..)

Comment: haha, thanks! I'd say Jetty isn't easily supported with NetBeans. Eclipse on the other-hand supports it down-right.. it's just I'm working on a collaborative project .. and everyone wants to use NetBeans. It's strange to note that not many people have asked for this.

Comment: @WulfgarPro I agree, there really should be a (working) plugin for it. And as luck has it I've got a project in the pipeline that I was going to use Jetty for, and now I've gotta figure a way round this!

Comment: That pluging seems to have been superseded by http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/54458/jetty-server-nb-1-0 . Please update your answer

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the Jetty plugin for Netbeans but it didn't work very well...
There is very little documentation and information about it on the internet.

I suggest to don't use it.
The Jetty for Eclipse (run-jetty-run at MarketPlace) work very better besides having too much more documentation about.

Comment: That pluging seems to have been superseded by plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/54458/jetty-server-nb-1-0 . Please update your answer